# "where" clause in php/mysql select-from-where problems

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do the following:

```
$query = 'Select first_name, last_name , user_name FROM table1 WHERE fullname = "$name_given"'
```

Where fullname is first_name + ' ' + last_name so shouldn't it look like:

```
$query = 'Select first_name, last_name FROM table1 WHERE concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) = "name_given"'
```

Except it doesn't work... tells me there isn't a column like that... and I don't store full name anywhere (and I don't think I'm allowed to add it) ... any help please?

EDIT: Oops, typed it in here wrong. I didn't copypasta'd it so yeah... syntaxically it was right...

EDIT2: FOUND IT. Apparnelty I need to put \"$name_given\" unless it'll just assume it's part of the quote... Thank you very much for answering my very poorly worded question.

Comment: what value stored in $name_given ? I mean $name_given is your full_name or something else like first_name or last_name..?

Comment: "name_given" is the name you're looking for, so like "David" or "john maximillian dewey" or "max mcfightmaster" or the like...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are concatenating `firstname` and `lastname`, not `first_name` and `last_name` (note the missing `_`).

Also, please do NOT use a variable unescaped in a query! Always escape it:

```
$query = "select ... where concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) = '"
    . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . '"';
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me which is better to use for security puposes. Like filter_var() or mysql_real_escape_string(). Thank you

Comment: `filter_var` is for general filtering (i.e. make sure an email is valid), but `mysql_real_escape_string` should *always* be used when passing variables to a SQL query - regardless if it has been filtered or not. The only exception that I accept is when I cast numbers to an integer with `(int)$var`.

Comment: thank you very much mate.. i was just wondering about it why mysql_real_escape_string if we can filter variable before passing to query. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You're not selecting from a table, you're attempting to concatinate two fields and select from the result, which doesn't make any sense.

Did you mean something like (note the changes to firstname and lastname):

```
$query = 'Select first_name, last_name FROM YourTable WHERE concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) = "name_given"'
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my code... notice the edit... it still doesn't work though =X